# Minimising distance between related items in an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, distance

I have an array of related items, { A, B, C, D }.

C is dependent on A.
D is dependent on B and C.

So, I calculate the total distance between items in this permutation as the sum of distances between: 
 C and A (2),
 D and B (2),
 D and C (1).
So, we have a total of 5 in this permutation.

However, the most optimal solution would be {A, C, D, B}, which has a total distance of 3.

I have a (much more complicated) list of about 200 items, which I want to optimise as best as I can, and I'm not aware of any sorting algorithms that sort in this way- can anyone point me in the direction of an existing algorithm?

From Comments:
A plot of the data would look like below- (Apologies for the formatting!)

```
#Dependencies #Items
            0      9
            1     27
            2     57
            3     55
            4     11
            5      3
            6      1
```

Comment: It is unclear what do you compare with what.

Comment: The closest that I'm getting to the value to sort upon is comparing distances from both upstream and downstream dependencies, swapping the items and then seeing if those two items have a greater total distance than previously. Even so, it's not particularly effective!

Comment: This explanation didn't help me to understand what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: @SalvadorDali The question is clear to me.  He wants to take a graph whose edges are called "dependencies", and create a flat list that minimizes the sum of the lengths between connected nodes.

Comment: I think you need to use something more complex, like some heuristic (tabu search would be my first option). Or just try all possibilities using Dynamic Programming to avoid testing the same case twice.

Comment: It seems this question is about graph minimum linear arrangement. This problem is NP-hard. But [approximation algorithm](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~isafro/papers/safrominla.pdf) exists.

Comment: What is the minimum/average/maximum number of dependencies of the items in your list? Could you perhaps post a histogram?

Comment: I've added a table with the number of dependencies, and the quantity of items with each (163 items in total)

Comment: Your proposed optimal solution `{A, C, D, B}` seems to be infeasible, as `D` is dependent on `C` and `B`, yet `D` precedes `B`.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Although www.clemson.edu is alive, people.cs.clemson.edu hasn't been responding the whole day, so the paper you linked to (I'm guessing it's this one: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677404001531) isn't freely available.

Comment: @m69: Yes, exactly this article, "Graph minimum linear arrangement by multilevel weighted edge contractions". And people.cs.clemson.edu is still responding (tested from several different addresses).

Comment: Maybe you should look into cluster analysis. Identifying strongly-connected subgroups could be a good first step, and then ordering them according to the number of connections between them. I don't know much about this, though, so I can't give any specific suggestions. (maybe you could add a cluster-analysis tag to reach out to people who know about this sort of thing)

Comment: I've added a cluster analysis tag- i think the paper at clemson.edu is the answer, once I can get my head around how it works!

Comment: This is not related to cluster analysis, whih doesn't do linear arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is Topological Sorting.

This algorithm is used in **directed graphs**. Here the alphabets form the nodes of the graph and the dependencies form the unidirectional edges. 
This algorithm is an application of depth first search and is used to order jobs.

[This](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-for-directed-acyclic-graphs/) is a pretty neat explanation.

Comment: The offered example has an optimal solution that places `D` after dependency `C` and before dependency `B`.  That's not a topological sort!  And even if he was interested in topological sorts, he'd still want the one with the smallest value for the distance function provided.